# How can I reproduce this painting effect?

Tags: walls, painting, paint

I really like this photowallpaper, but it's quite impossible to import it:

[image: Pattern]

I think - based on my basic but quite good paining skills - I can reproduce it with painting. But..

- which type of paint is good for this? I think it should be dense and a little bit "rough"
- how can I reproduce the pattern? with brush and sponge?
- any general idea?

Comment: Is this a concrete or stone wall because if so then you can get an acid stain that will give it this look. Painting drywall though... i have no idea.

Comment: you could texture with premix joint compound, though using setting mud would be faster.  OTOOH, thick Premix will crack..  try hitting it with a hair dryer.

Answer (score 1):

I know (think) there is an additive you can put in paint or a glaze to give it the crack effect.  Or I believe it is hand painted sometimes.

http://www.diynetwork.com/how-to/how-to-apply-a-crackle-finish/index.html
http://makethebestofthings.blogspot.com/2010/05/crackle-finish-with-elmers-glue.html